# Using 503 page when my site is in maintenance mode

Tags: php

This is my code for 503 page:

header.php

```
if(getOption('maintence_mode')==1)
{
header("location:503.php");
exit;
}
```

503.php

```
<?php 
$protocol = "HTTP/1.0";
if ( "HTTP/1.1" == $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] )
$protocol = "HTTP/1.1";
header( "$protocol 503 Service Unavailable", true, 503 );
header( "Retry-After: 3600" );  
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Page Not Found </title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="6;url=index.php">

    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>Site is currently in maintenance mode.</h2>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I want to know if my code is correct and how Google will handle SEO thing.  I don't have much knowledge about this, so it would be very helpful if someone could validate this code.

Comment: Isn't `if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])=='503.php')` always going to be true?

Comment: I noticed you're using a relative URI, `503.php`. I suggest making it an absolute URI. To quote [php.net's documentation for location](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php): HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to `Location:` including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs. You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself. [Example code here, scroll down to second to last "Note" section.](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: Old but actual article from Google blog: [How to deal with planned site downtime](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-deal-with-planned-site-downtime.html)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It looks good to me, but I do have one thing to say.

If I want to access `http://yourdomain.com/example/page`, and get a 503 error, I want to be able to refresh the page in a little while, to see if the 503 error is lifted.

What you do is redirect the user to the 503 page, which means that the address I'll get now if I refresh is `http://yourdomain.com/503.php`, this is not optimal.

Instead of redirecting, **include** the 503 error page.

---

Also some other things:

- The error says 503, but your titles says "Page not Found"
- Code indentation is important. Don't neglect it!
- Never use an `if` block without curly brackets. Never.

Comment: "Instead of redirecting, include the 503 error page." - yes, as mentioned... also if you redirect the first response the client gets is a **302**, not the intended 503. (Bit of an aside, but the URL in a location header should be absolute, not relative.)

Comment: "Never use an `if` block without curly brackets. Never." +1 You're a good man.

Answer (score 20):

**Maintenance Code**

In addition to the good points of @Madara Uchiha:

You use `header Retry-After` in addition to `http-equiv="refresh"`, which seems odd. The `http-equiv="refresh"` will redirect the user after 6 seconds to `index.php`, making the `header Retry-After` useless. The [W3C recommends against using meta refresh](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-CORE-TECHS/#auto-page-refresh), and I think in your situation the `header Retry-After` is a better solution, as first redirecting the user to `503.php`, and then to `index.php`, from where it will probably go to `503.php` again is confusing.

Of course, then you need to include instead of redirect as @Madara Uchiha recommended, otherwise the user will stay on `503.php` forever. But as an include is a lot more user friendly than a redirect (user stays on page and can reload manually), this is not a problem.

**SEO & Google**

Returning `503` is how google recommends to [handle planned downtime](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2011/01/how-to-deal-with-planned-site-downtime.html), so this is definitely the way to go. 
Google is not 100% transparent on how it determents placement in search results, but downtime is one variable that will [negatively affect your standing](http://community.shoppingcartelite.com/blog/how-website-downtime-affects-your-seo), so try do reduce it as much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Small nitpick: You're missing the initial `<html>` tag.

Comment: You need to add a little bit more information than that.

Comment: @JaDogg The answer is short, but it does suggest a concrete improvement. I think it is [sufficient to be an answer](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1479/9357).

Comment: @200_success Yes you are correct, that is a big improvement, I've also up-voted it. However adding more information will attract more up votes.